# How do I replace a basic exception with another one?

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code

```
try {
    ....
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(String.format(SOME_CUSTOM_VARIABLE, e);
    throw e;
}
```

I want the exception to get the string SOME_CUSTOM_STRING_WITH_VARIABLES.
So what I want to do is

```
try {
    ....
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(String.format(SOME_CUSTOM_VARIABLE, e);
    throw new Exception(SOME_CUSTOM_VARIABLE, e);
}
```

But this forces me to add "throws Exception" to the method signature.
This method threw an exception anyhow. Why do I have to change the signature?

How do I replace a basic exception with another one?

Answer (score 0):

Because throwing an exception means creating your own `Exception` that your method `throws` so you need to declare that the method `throws` it so that users of the method know to `catch` it.  Like how you had to surround whatever it was in a try-catch in the first place.
If it wasn't enforced that you declare that your method `throws` then `Exception`s could just go missing.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you have [checked exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) - these must be declared by the throwing method - and unchecked, which need not be. (And then there are `Error`'s, but let's leave them aside for now).

Not going into the details of which exception strategy to use, basically you can throw any exception that is a or extends from [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) without having to declare it on your method. Eg. you could

```
void myMethod() { // no 'throws' declaration
    try {
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException( SOME_CUSTOM_VARIABLE , e );
    }
}
```

I'll recommend [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation) and [this blog post](http://techblog.bozho.net/checked-and-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/) for a good discussion on the topic.

On the question of replacing an exception with another in the `throws` clause: I understand that your method already threw some exception which isn't specifically `java.lang.Exception`. In that case, you're mostly out of luck - you can only "replace" the thrown exception with the same or a subclassed one, otherwise you'll have to edit/add to the `throws` clause.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the method signature, you could create a custom `RuntimeException` and throw it.

Be aware of consequences though :

- If this custom `RuntimeException` is not properly catch in upper classes, it could crash the entire program.
- It's more like a workaround, when a `RuntimeException` is thrown, the program should not recover from the exception. Runtime exceptions represent problems that are the result of a programming problem.

Some information about this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Answer (score 0):

> But this forces me to add "throws Exception" to the method signature.This method threw an exception anyhow. Why do I have to change the signature?

It depends, if you are throwing [checked exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions) then java compiler will force you to handle it i.e. you need to include it in method signature or handle it in the method body. 
BUT if you throw [unchecked exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) than there is no need to modify the method signature

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you don't solve this by throwing a `RuntimeException`.
Those are strictly the preserve of the JVM and it would be dreadful style to use one just to avoid declaring a throw clause.

The name and purpose of the Java exceptions is (IMHO) confused.
You should stick to the idea that things subclassed from `Exception` need handlers and things derived from `Error` don't. Ignore the rule-breaker `RuntimeException` and complain bitterly to your mates down the pub and random people on stackoverflow.com that it ought to just be called `RuntimeError` and sub-class `Error` (for f**ks sake).

If you really have a condition where a method has a throws clause declaring an `Exception` but you have good reason to now throw it up then I suggest you sub-class `Error` to either `UnexpectedExceptionError` or `UnhandledExceptionError`.

Use the first if the `Exception` is 'not supposed to be possible - such as an abstract I/O method that you know is backed by (say) a string in memory and can't really throw `IOException` despite the interface declaration.

Use the second if throwing the  `Exception` would break the signature of some method you're implementing/overriding that can't be modified to advertise the potential `Exception`.

As a third-way it's natural for exceptions to propagate to the `run()` method of `Runnable`.
In those cases I recommend passing the `Exception` to some overseer process as a kind of suicide note because whatever you throw out of `run()` will get ignored anyway and you probably want do something to recognize complete failure of a `Thread`!

**PS:** If you're doing this because you're lazy and don't want to handle exceptions properly, may you be cursed to maintain code written by someone with the same attitude :)